# Is it possible to create a sklearn multivariate polynomial regression that is cubic in one term and linear in the other?

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, regression, non-linear-regression

I am trying to model a relationship in python using multiple terms including a time term but the model I am trying to recreate is one that uses a cubic polynomial in one variable and a linear polynomial in the time term. In other words, the model is in the following form:

```
y = c1 + c2*x + c3*x**2 + c4*x**3 + c5*time + error
```

I have already used sklearn to create a polynomial regression to model the relationship between x and y but I am struggling to understand how to to extend this model to include a linear time term.

I have tried to approach the problem using the built in multivariate regression features but these seem to always put the relationship between all involved terms as a cubic relationship. The (very primitive) code I utilized for this was the following:

```
xtime = = np.stack([x,time],axis=1)
polyfeatures = PolynomialFeatures(degree=3)
feat = polyfeatures.fit_transform(xtime)
for i in range(len(feat)):
    feat[i][4] = 0
    feat[i][5] = 0
    feat[i][7] = 0
    feat[i][8] = 0
    feat[i][9] = 0
```

The thinking behind this was to zero out all of the exponent values in feat that corresponded to terms that were not in the final equation that I was looking to create.
The result of this attempt was (unsurprisingly) a very poor regression that did not correlate with the data whatsoever.

If anyone has any recommendations I would be extremely grateful. Thank you so much for any help!

Comment: In this case, time is a numpy array of values starting at 0 for the year of the original data point and ending at the number of years after the initial year the readings took place. (ex. if the initial year is 2012 and the final year is 2022, the array spans from 0 to 10)

Comment: Why don't you introduce a set of new variables as in `z1 = x`, `z2 = x^2`, and `z3 = x^3` then treat them as a multivariate linear regression?